# Search Chinese text in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, utf-8

I have stored the Chinese characters in the database like follow.

```
{
  "zh":"\u6df1\u5165\u4e86\u89e3\uff0c\r\n\u7d55\u4f73\u5564\u9152\u8207\u7f8e\u5473\u98df\u7269 \u80cc\u5f8c\u7684\u6211\u5011\uff01",
  "en":"\u6df1\u5165\u4e86\u89e3\uff0c\r\n\u7d55\u4f73\u5564\u9152\u8207\u7f8e\u5473\u98df\u7269 \u80cc\u5f8c\u7684\u6211\u5011\uff01"
}
```

Now, I want to search for them using `吉比鮮釀餐廳`

Please suggest, how actually we can achieve this?

Comment: Why you're converting strings to strange unicodes in your DB ?
You can insert Chinese characters into MySQL using the appropriate encoding

Comment: I have used Laravel and multi language plugin which saved the Chinese and English like that in the database.

Comment: Could you please add a screen capture of your table columns types and encoding

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Please provide `CHAR_LENGTH()`, `LENGTH()` and `HEX()` of a sample bit of text.  We need to figure out whether `\u6df1` is _stored_ as 6 ascii characters or 1 Chinese utf8 character.  `吉比鮮釀餐廳` would give 6, 18, and E59089E6AF94E9AEAEE98780E9A490E5BBB3 .

Comment: Here is the laravel package I used. https://github.com/rinvex/laravel-pages and here is the screenshot of database table structure https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4648143/97fd603f65beb4c6dd24722cdc840480